# How can components be dynamically rendered inside another component in Nuxt 3 projects correctly?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am unable to render icon components dynamically inside a navigation component.

I created a `Dashboard` icon inside `components/icons` directory

```
<script setup>

</script>

<template>
  <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M22 8.52V3.98C22 2.57 21.36 2 19.77 2H15.73C14.14 2 13.5 2.57 13.5 3.98V8.51C13.5 9.93 14.14 10.49 15.73 10.49H19.77C21.36 10.5 22 9.93 22 8.52Z" fill="#28A745"/>
    <path d="M22 19.77V15.73C22 14.14 21.36 13.5 19.77 13.5H15.73C14.14 13.5 13.5 14.14 13.5 15.73V19.77C13.5 21.36 14.14 22 15.73 22H19.77C21.36 22 22 21.36 22 19.77Z" fill="#28A745"/>
    <path d="M10.5 8.52V3.98C10.5 2.57 9.86 2 8.27 2H4.23C2.64 2 2 2.57 2 3.98V8.51C2 9.93 2.64 10.49 4.23 10.49H8.27C9.86 10.5 10.5 9.93 10.5 8.52Z" fill="#28A745"/>
    <path d="M10.5 19.77V15.73C10.5 14.14 9.86 13.5 8.27 13.5H4.23C2.64 13.5 2 14.14 2 15.73V19.77C2 21.36 2.64 22 4.23 22H8.27C9.86 22 10.5 21.36 10.5 19.77Z" fill="#28A745"/>
  </svg>
</template>
```

And then created the `Navigation` component inside the `components` directory

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

const routes = [
  { name: 'Dashboard', path: '/dashboard', icon: 'IconsDashboard'},
];

const currentRoute = useRoute();
</script>

<template>
  <div class="mb-9">
    <p class="mb-2 text-xs text-gray-400 font-normal uppercase tracking-widest">
      Admin
    </p>

    <ul class="text-base font-normal capitalize gap-y-5">
      <li v-for="route in routes">
        <NuxtLink :to="route.path" >
          <p class="flex flex-row gap-2">
            <component :is="route.icon" />
            {{ route.name }}
          </p>
        </NuxtLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding the following to the script

```
import { IconsDashboard }

const routes = [
  { name: 'Dashboard', path: '/dashboard', icon: IconsDashboard },
];
```